# Why does Doxygen return `no uniquely matching class member found for` when the class member exists in PHP?

Tags: php, inheritance, documentation, doxygen

There's a class hierarchy in my project that goes somehow like this:

```
+-------------+
|   Manager   |
+------+------+
       |
+------+------+
|ClosedManager|
+------+------+
       |
+------+------+
|ConfigManager|
+-------------+
```

`ConfigManager` reimplements a protected method `initManager` introduced in `Manager`

**Manager**

```
/**
 * The construction method for `ManagerInterface` classes
 *
 * @param array $managerConfig
 */
protected function initManager(array $managerConfig = array()) {
}
```

**ConfigManager**

```
/**
 *
 * @inheritdoc
 */
protected function initManager(array $managerConfig = array()) {
    /**
     *
     * @var \DigitalPublications\Midas\Manager\PathsManager $pathsManager
     */
    $pathsManager = $this->options->get('pathsManager', $managerConfig);

    $this->pool['userDefined'] = new Config(array(
        'path' => $pathsManager->get('userDefinedConfig')
    ));
    $this->pool['wordpressOptions'] = new Config(array(
        'path' => $pathsManager->get('wordpressOptionsConfig')
    ));
    $this->pool['productTypesSchemas'] = new Config(array(
        'path' => $pathsManager->get('productTypesSchemasConfig'),
        'canReturnAll' => FALSE,
    ));
}
```

When I run `Doxygen`, I get this error:

```
ConfigManager.php:27: warning: no uniquely matching class member found
for initManager(array $managerConfig=array())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `@internal` tag in the comment block, so that you can still document the method's body and don't 'confuse' `Doxygen`

```php
/**
 * @internal
 * @var \DigitalPublications\Midas\Manager\PathsManager $pathsManager
*/
```

Comment: Probably the `/* ... */` would have worked for you as well, doxygen should only see `/**` and `///` type constructs. You try to document something internal variable of a method, maybe the `@internal` command in this comment block might be of use as well.

Comment: @albert you are absolutely right. With @internal you can document the body of the method and don't confuse `Doxygen` as well